# symfony2 doctrine2 batch processing error with entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entity, batch-processing

i am trying to insert a lot of entities to DB. When i try to insert to example 5 entities with this code it works without problem... but when i implemented the batch method there it causes this error:

(code)

```
        if (!empty($invite_this_peopleArray)) {
            $batchSize = 20;
            $i = 0;
            foreach ($explodeInviteArray as $explodingUser) {
                ++$i;

                $notifiedUser=$userRepo->find($explodingUser);

                $notify=new Notify();
                $notify->setNotifyUser($user);
                $notify->setUser($notifiedUser);
                $notify->setStatus($lastStatus);
                $notify->setTyp('invite');
                $notify->setViewed(false);
                $notify->setAdInfo($name);

                $em->persist($notify);

                if (($i % $batchSize) === 0) {
                    $em->flush();
                    $em->clear(); // Detaches all objects from Doctrine!
                }            
            }
        }
```

Error:

```
A new entity was found through the relationship 'TB\NotifyBundle\Entity\Notify#notifyUser' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: (nick of notify user user($user->getUsername())). To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}).
```

What is the problem please?

BTW: when i modified the code so i clear only $notify and $notifiedUser like:

```
                if (($i % $batchSize) === 0) {
                    $em->flush();
                    $em->clear($notify); // Detaches all objects from Doctrine!
                    $em->clear($notifiedUser); // Detaches all objects from Doctrine!
                }
```

The error is gone but i try to insert 4000 rows and i am getting insted this error:

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php on line 514
```

When i try insert 1000 rows.

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes)
```

(so there is somewhere memory leak? )

Comment: I had this exact same issue with APC, what I did was changing the configuration for it inside the php.ini file allowing it to use more memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue is coming from this line.  It would appear the the `$user` Object is not a managed Doctrine Entity.

`$notify->setNotifyUser($user);`

Comment: The maximum execution time is probably a PHP configuration issue.  I would recommending checking your PHP configuration and upping the max script execution time.

Comment: Even if that would work... still i dont think its good to have script running so long... the script is for invite to group function so is runing often... any other ideas?

Comment: So is 4000+ row inserts going to be pretty typical per run?

Comment: No... the insert will be usally from 0-100 rows. The 4000 users has only few admins on page. I edited my question check it please.

Comment: Depending on how complex your object graph is, you may have to increase your PHP allowed max memory usage or decrease your batch size.

Comment: Hm :( ... and how could i check exactly how complet the object graph is?

Comment: Your object graph is the models and relationships you've defined.  So it really just comes down to how many fields each of your entities has.  One of my projects has an extremely large objects and required us to allowed memory usage to 1024M

Comment: Yes i know what is it but if i can somehow completel var_dump it.. or something like that?. Because i have bad feeling that on the user object what i do select from DB as well in that loop has too many (not fields i think its not problem have about 20fields with small data) but has a lot of relationships. So i would like to show it to you and you can check or?

Comment: Unfortunately there really is no easy way other than dumping the most top-level object in the object chain and looking at it from there or dumping the individual objects. So here we probably should dump `$user`, `$notifiedUser`, `$lastStatus` and `$notify`?

Comment: okay i am going to. But actually this is how the table looks like: http://www.upnito.sk/0/4zs7rcztmzb9ctxrxfwkq2dy7buy3x4u.png so... it would be much easier to insert even 4000 rows if i would dont need to care about objects but insert just numbers right? (but there are foreign keys so symfony does not let me insert instead only the number of foreign key value right?... )

Comment: Yeah, you could manage the relationships yourself and then just insert the IDs which would definitely decrease the memory usage but also means more logic that you have to write. You'll have to use the Doctrine QueryBuilder or SQL to retrieve related objects but it's pretty straight forward.

Comment: I have question please. How can i insert multiple inserts at once? I have $conn->insert('notify', array(bla bla)) but i need to group them for speed. Cant find it in google somehow.

Comment: Fixed with Connection#transactional($func):. Marking as answer even if  it was more teoretical but thanks for your time. Just please check my basic user object. http://pastebin.com/0H4xddGR

Comment: Oops, just saw this.  Glad you got it working!  Transactions are def the way to go for bulk inserts.

Comment: can you check the pastebin i posted here please? :)

Comment: User object looks good, I don't see anything that would cause concern for a memory leak.  It is a fairly large object though so you might find that you'll hit your PHP memory limit when retrieving a large number of users from the database or doing large inserts using Doctrine.